# Promisifying battlenet-api library

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to custom-promisify the [battlenet-api](https://github.com/benweier/battlenet-api) library, and it has the following function signature:

```
function (args, callback)
```

Where `callback`'s signature is:

```
function (err, body, res)
```

In this particular case, I need to add a rate limiter ([node-rate-limiter](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter)) to the promise prior to its execution, so the function would be like this:

```
function throttler(originalMethod) {
    // return a function
    return function throttled() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        // Needed so that the original method can be called with the correct receiver
        var self = this;

        // which returns a promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // We call the originalMethod here because if it throws,
            // it will reject the returned promise with the thrown error
            rateLimiterByHour.removeTokens(1, function() {
                 rateLimiterBySecond.removeTokens(1, function() {
                     originalMethod.apply(self, args, function(err, body, res) {
                             if (err) { reject(err, body, res); }
                             else { resolve({err, body, res}); }
                         };
                     });
                 );
             });
        });
    };
};

Promise.promisifyAll(require('battlenet-api').wow, {
    promisifier: throttler
});
```

`throttler` is

I am not sure at all whether this would work, or whether I should take another approach.

How could I promisify this appropriately?

Comment: What is `throttler.throttle`?

Comment: A placeholder reference to the throttling library I was using. I've added it to the original for clarification.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should about work. However, `reject` does only take a single argument, and if `err` is falsy you probably don't want to pass it as part of your fulfillment value:

```
if (err) reject(err); 
else resolve({body, res});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should work. One problem however is that the `originalMethod` callback has to be part of the `args` array in order to be passed in by `Function#apply`. Something like:

```
var callback = function(err, body, res) {
                   if (err) { reject(err); }
                   else { resolve({body, res}); }
               }
...
originalMethod.apply(self, args.concat(callback));
```